# How can I set the focus on DecimalUpDown via Button Command base on validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, mvvm

XAML View Code

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding InitialDepositAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="{Binding MinimumAllowedAmount}" Maximum="{Binding MaximumAllowedAmount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="21" Margin="5 0 0 0" />

<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding CardPaymentAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="{Binding MinimumAllowedAmount}" Maximum="{Binding MaximumAllowedAmount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="21" Margin="5 0 0 0" />

<Button Command="{Binding ProccessButtonCommand}" BorderBrush="#a7a7a7" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="162" Height="42" Margin="0 10 0 0">
```

ViewModel Code

```
 private void ExecuteProccessButtonCommand(object obj)
 {
    if (InitialDepositAmount == 100)
    //Focus Initial Depostit DecimalUpDown
    if (CardPaymentAmount== 100)
    //Focus Card Payment DecimalUpDown
 }

 private DelegateCommand<object> _proccessButtonCommand;
 public DelegateCommand<object> ProccessButtonCommand =>
    _proccessButtonCommand ? ? (_proccessButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object> (ExecuteProccessButtonCommand));
```

The logic goes like this. I would only like approach that uses only MVVM.

Comment: Are the `InitialDepositAmount` and `CardPaymentAmount` exclusive? To which control do you want to set focus if both conditions are `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could created an attached behavior for `DecimalUpDown` that has a condition and target button. You need to use the [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package for this.

```
public class FocusConditionBehavior : Behavior<DecimalUpDown>
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Target), typeof(ButtonBase), typeof(FocusConditionBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTargetChanged));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ConditionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Condition), typeof(bool), typeof(FocusConditionBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

   public ButtonBase Target
   {
      get => (ButtonBase)GetValue(TargetProperty);
      set => SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
   }

   public bool Condition
   {
      get => (bool)GetValue(ConditionProperty);
      set => SetValue(ConditionProperty, value);
   }

   private static void OnTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      ((FocusConditionBehavior)d).OnTargetChanged((ButtonBase)e.OldValue, (ButtonBase)e.NewValue);
   }

   private void OnTargetChanged(ButtonBase oldButtonBase, ButtonBase newButtonBase)
   {
      if (oldButtonBase != null)
         oldButtonBase.Click -= OnClick;

      if (newButtonBase != null)
         newButtonBase.Click += OnClick;
   }

   private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (Condition)
         Keyboard.Focus(AssociatedObject);
   }
}
```

Create `bool` properties in your view model that represent the conditions. Make sure that you update these properties using `INotifyPropertyChanged` when the corresponding data properties change to notify the user interface of changes.

```
public bool IsInitialDepositAmountMatching
{
   get
   {
      // You are free to add any conditions here
      return InitialDepositAmount == 100;
   }
}
```

Then assign a name to the button that should trigger evaluating the conditions and focusing, e.g. `TestButton` and attach the beahvior with appropriate bindings to the `DecimalUpDown`s.

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown>
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:FocusConditionBehavior Condition="{Binding IsInitialDepositAmountMatching}"
                                    Target="{Binding ElementName=TestButton}"/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</xctk:DecimalUpDown>
<xctk:DecimalUpDown>
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:FocusConditionBehavior Condition="{Binding IsCardPaymentAmountMatching}"
                                    Target="{Binding ElementName=TestButton}"/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</xctk:DecimalUpDown>
```

This way, focusing is handled MVVM-compliant in the view and is packed as reusable component as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks for this. Should I add the FocusOnClickBehavior class on a different file?

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos Yes, you should put it in a separate file. By the way, I changed to code, so it spells `Properties`. Be sure to update all.

Comment: Also on this scenario can I add a conditional statement since the element should not be focused on some conditions. Thank you.

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos Of course you can. You can do that in `OnClick`, or you create additional dependency properties to bind properties for your conditions. Even better, create a single dependency property like `IsEnabled` and then bind it in XAML. This way, you can use a converter or even mulit-value converters to bind properties and the logic for your conditions is not within the focus properties itself, which also makes binding easier.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused can you show me how I handle it on the ViewModel part? And the local:FocusOnClickProperties.Target shouldn't it be local:FocusOnClickProperties.SetTarget? Sorry I am kinda new in WPF.

Comment: I'll elaborate the code. I think this might not be able to cater to the logic I need. Appreciate you answer thank you so much.

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos `local:FocusOnClickProperties.Target` is right, XAML calls `SetTarget` automatically, that why there is a naming convention for getters setters and dependency properties.

Comment: Can you see my updated code if this is still applicable?

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos I have changed the answer. Please make sure that you provide a minimal and complete example of the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me all the way but I can't seem to make it work with your example. I tried setting the x:Name and Name of the Button. Would you like to chat if possible? And is it possible to make the bool not readonly I would like to set multiple condition that will make the bool true.

Comment: You do not have the Chat privilege, yet. I canged minor things for better understanding, but again I have tested it and it works. Please debug in `OnTargetChanged` if a button is even passed, if not your binding may be wrong or there is a typo in the element name. In `OnClick` please debug, if the condition ever changes to true, if not and the conditions are true, then you are missing property changed notifications.

Comment: Dude I finally found out why its not working properly its on the OnPropertyChanged() part it all works now. Your answer and patience on this question is really amazing. I hope you're doin good! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi I would like to ask if its possible to omit the button part like it gets focused as long as the bool condition changes on the viewmodel regardless of the action that caused it?

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos Of course. Remove all the button related code from the behavior, and add a property changed handler to the `Condition` property, like `new PropertyMetadata(null, OnConditionChanged)`. Then create the `OnConditionChanged` method an just check the condition and focus like in `OnClick`.

Comment: Okay I'll try doing this I hope it works fine. Thanks :)

Comment: I did it like this but it has causes error

`private static void OnConditionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((FocusConditionBehavior)d).OnConditionChanged();
        }

        private void OnConditionChanged()
        {
            if (Condition)
                Keyboard.Focus(AssociatedObject);
        }`

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos You do not necessarily need a behavior. Please look at your recent question, I have provided an answer that should be easier for you than adapting this behavior.